# Lift laws and maintanance in a residential flat

Tags: criminal-law, india, tenant, punishment, indian-penal-code

In India, what are the legal facilities/minimum maintanance requirements (Like alarms, phones, power back up etc) for a lift installed in a residential flat?Who are responsible for any accidents caused by poor maintanance?

I had a bad experience in my flat where i am staying as a tenant. I was stuck for an hour as alarms and phones were not working in the lift. Later I came to know earlier a family vacated the place as they were stuck for an hour with their 6 months old baby. And no one seems to care, as nobody is hurt yet! Is there any protection in our law making lift maintanance mandatory? And who is responsible for this in a gated community. The care taker took a stance like they are answerable only to the owners. So residents have zero say in this??

Hope there are some Indian laws which i can make the care taker aware of.

Comment: I don't know the situation in India, but in many places the responsibility for regulating and/or inspecting lifts lies with the municipality.  In a federation such as India you'll need to consider local, state, and federal law.  For example, the Government of Karnataka has a Department of Electrical Inspectorate which is also responsible for inspecting lifts [under the Karnataka Lifts, Escalators and Passenger conveyors Act, 2012](http://www.ksei.gov.in/lifts.htm).